# SQL Server - How to prioritize where conditions in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a DB table ( say student ) which has below sample data

```
Name   ID    Active  admissionDate ReleaseDate  Nationality
John   3572  1       06/02/2014    06/02/2018   0
Sandy  2748  1       06/02/2013    11/01/2016   1
```

Now I want to select total 10000 students. 
first condition would be Active = 1 (say there are 7000 such students ).
second condition would be Nationality = 1 (Rest of the 3000 students as total required students are 10K).
All odered by admissionDate

What I want to achieve here it should fetch total 10000 students but first priority will be active = 1 and second priority will be nationality = 1.
Initially I select students on the first condition and stored in a temp table. Then I deducted count of temp table from 10000 and select the remaining students with second condition and append in temp table again.

But I want to achieve it in one single query as original table is very large and its taking too much execution time . Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but i think this is easily solved by a `ORDER BY` and `CASE` expression. This is psuedo-sql, however:

```
WITH Students AS(
    SELECT TOP 10000 [YourColumns]
    FROM Student S
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN Active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
             CASE WHEN Nationality = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
             CASE WHEN ... )
SELECT *
FROM Students
ORDER BY AdmissionDate;
```

This means you're not limiting your data set in the `WHERE` clause, however, the data will need to be sorted first, pushing those that are active to the top first, then those with a Nationality of 1, etc, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `order by` with the conditions you want:

```
select top (1000) s.*
from students s
order by (case when Active = 1 then 1
               when Nationality = 1 then 2
               else 3
          end),
         AdmissionDate desc;
```

This assumes you want the most recent admissions first.  Just drop the `desc` if you want the earliest ones first.